# How to make custom integration in erpnext

Tags: customization, erpnext, frappe

I am trying to integrate erpnext to my own marketplace so i can directly fetch orders related data in erpnext, so anyone have any idea regarding this like how can i sync erpnext with my online store so, order related data or any other type of data will be automatically sync with erpnext from online store.

Any kind of ideas or suggestions are helpful.

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out existing Integrations in ERPNext e.g. WooCommerce, Shopify

For syncing data from your MarketPlace to ERPNext, either you need to publish that data from Market Place to ERPNext my making APIs in ERPNext.

A good starting point would be to check ERPNext documentation for [Shopify](https://docs.erpnext.com/docs/v13/user/manual/en/erpnext_integration/shopify_integration) and [WooCommerce](https://docs.erpnext.com/docs/v13/user/manual/en/erpnext_integration/woocommerce_integration).

Docs for writing rest api:
https://frappeframework.com/docs/user/en/api/rest

Answer (score 0):

You can use hooks to sync data from ERPNext to your store. For instance you can update order status in your store when item shipped.

Source: https://frappeframework.com/docs/user/en/python-api/hooks

You can develop a rest api to create sales orders in the ERPNext when an order is created in your store.

Source: https://frappeframework.com/docs/user/en/api/rest

Most probably you will have several rest api methods to retrieve customers, addresses, items etc.